# Formatting FOCUS component specifications

Tags: formatting

I am trying to write specifications in the FOCUS framework* with LaTeX. Such a specification has the following syntactical form:
[image: FOCUS specification syntax]

I have tried tackling the problem with tabularx but I am not getting anywhere. The header is especially tricky and I dont feel like this is the way to go, as I would have to embed the declarations and body into table-cells. The Body of a FOCUS specification can be anything from a boolean formula to a graph, so a general solution would have to be quite flexible.

Is there any package that can create boxes like this one?

<sub>* Broy, M., & Stølen, K. (2012). Specification and development of interactive systems: focus on streams, interfaces, and refinement. Springer Science & Business Media.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You could try with a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\NewTColorBox{focuscomponent}{ O{} m m }{
    enhanced,
    frame empty,
    boxsep=13.5pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    middle=0pt,
    colback=white!0,
    coltitle=black,
    segmentation style={solid, black},
    fontupper=\itshape,
    fontlower=\itshape,
    overlay={
        \draw (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- 
            ([yshift=2pt]interior.north west) -- 
            ([yshift=2pt]interior.north east);
        \draw (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east); 
        \node[font=\itshape, anchor=base west, fill=white, inner sep=3.5pt] 
            at ([xshift=10pt]interior.north west) {#2};
        \node[font=\itshape, anchor=base east, fill=white, inner sep=3.5pt] 
            at ([xshift=-10pt]interior.north east) {#3};
    },
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{focusitemize}{ }{
    \begin{list}{}{
        \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\normalfont\sffamily ##1}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{3em}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{3em}
    }
}{
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{focuscomponent}{Name}{Frame\_Labels}
        \begin{focusitemize}
            \item[in] Input\_Declarations 
            \item[out] Output\_Declarations
        \end{focusitemize}
        \tcblower
        Body
    \end{focuscomponent}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, this looks very promising and it does produce the same output in my document. I have tested it with some math-environments as the body-part and it seems to work. I'm just curious: Is the overlay-stuff tikz commands?

Comment: @MerlinDenker Yes it is Ti*k*Z. It is probably possible to solve this in a simpler way, but I was not able to come up with a better solution. I don't know how you want to use this eventually, but this solution should work with math contents.

Comment: It does work with math-content and with graphs drawn in TikZ. Just what I needed. Thank you very much!